# Regex: How to put a word, that starts with any letter (except special characters and digits) to the previous line?

Tags: regex

Example:

```
"Football is
great."
```

to

```
"Football is great."
```

Tried the following:

```
preg_replace("/\n[a-zA-Z]/","",$cont);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are a way to match text, not change it. Changing text would be the job of the programming language in which regular expressions are implemented. From your question, I suspect you're using PHP. Can you please [edit your question]() and add more details, including relevant language tags, and more code to provide context? It's likely that this is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), as you're asking for a way to implement your solution rather than asking how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$cont = preg_replace('/\R(?=\h*[a-zA-Z])/', "", $cont);
```

`\R` matches any newline in `PCRE` and lookahead makes sure newline is followed by 0 or more whitespace and then English alphabets.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS8tD7/3)

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `/`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If OP wants to support unicode then use `/\R(?=\h*\p{L})/u` as regex above

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex demo in python. It will search and replace new line in string wrapped by double quotes.

```
import re

data = """
"Football is
great."

"""

match = re.search(r"\".*?([\r\n]+).*\"", data, re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    result = match.group().replace("\n", " ")
else:
    result = data

print(result)
```

Output:

```
"Football is great."
```

But it will not match or replace

```
"Football is great on same line."
```